# How to write code to query sequelize model with where parameter in nested table

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

My database has a users, likes, dislikes, parcels table.

The likes, dislikes, parcels tables are linked to the users table by the user_id field, which is present in each of the linked tables.

How to sort likes in the users table that have deleted = false field values.
If I make a request to the users model where

```
let users = await models.users.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Likes,
      as: "likes",          
    },
    {
      model: Dislikes,
      as: "dislikes",          
    },
    {
      model: Parcels,
      as: "parcels",          
    },
  ],
  where: {
    deleted: false,
  },
});
```

In this case, I get all the values ​​of the users table, where the field deleted = false.

```
    let users = await models.users.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Likes,
      as: "likes",
      where: {
        deleted: false,
      },
    },
    {
      model: Dislikes,
      as: "dislikes",
     
    },
    {
      model: Parcels,
      as: "parcels",
     
    },
  ],
  where: {
    deleted: false,
  },
});
```

The text of the request that sequelize generates

SELECT `users`.`id_user`,
`users`.`name_1`,
`users`.`name_2`,
`users`.`name_3`,
`users`.`nation`,
`users`.`citizenship`,
`users`.`dateOfBirth`,
`users`.`placeOfWork`,
`users`.`education`,
`users`.`url_photo`,
`users`.`deleted`,
`likes`.`id_like` AS `likes.id_like`,
`likes`.`id_user` AS `likes.id_user`,
`likes`.`date` AS `likes.date`,
`likes`.`deleted` AS `likes.deleted`,
`dislikes`.`id_dislike` AS `dislikes.id_dislike`,
`dislikes`.`id_user` AS `dislikes.id_user`,
`dislikes`.`date` AS `dislikes.date`,
`parcels`.`id_parcel` AS `parcels.id_parcel`,
`parcels`.`id_user` AS `parcels.id_user`,
`parcels`.`date` AS `parcels.date`,
`parcels`.`deleted` AS `parcels.deleted`
FROM `users` AS `users`
INNER JOIN `likes` AS `likes` ON `users`.`id_user` = `likes`.`id_user`
AND `likes`.`deleted` = FALSE
LEFT OUTER JOIN `dislikes` AS `dislikes` ON `users`.`id_user` = `dislikes`.`id_user`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `parcels` AS `parcels` ON `users`.`id_user` = `parcels`.`id_user`
WHERE `users`.`deleted` = FALSE;

In this case, I get only those records of the users table that have records in the likes table, respectively, all records in the user table and in the likes table have the field deleted = false.

However, I need to retrieve all records from the users table whether they have related records from the likes table or not. And also all records must have a field deleted - false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that I got your question, but it seems that `required: false` is what you need:

```js
let users = await models.users.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Likes,
      as: "likes",
      where: {
        deleted: false,
      },
      required: false,
    },
    {
      model: Dislikes,
      as: "dislikes",
     
    },
    {
      model: Parcels,
      as: "parcels",
     
    },
  ],
  where: {
    deleted: false,
  },
});
```

Comment: yes this is what I need.